# KL25 DAC Driver shows no output on oscilloscope

Tags: c, driver, dac

I am writing a DAC driver for the Freedom KL25z and it does not work. I am testing it with an oscilloscope, but there is no rise in voltage.

My configuration function is using the **only** DAC channel available for the KL25...

Connected oscilloscope voltage to PORTE30 pin and oscilloscope ground to KL25 GND pin.

## UPDATE, forgot to write filenames and actual question

Here is my DACDriver.c file

```
#include "DACDriver.h"
unsigned char bflgSendingData = 0;
unsigned short* wpSetPattern;
unsigned short wSetPatternSize;

void vfnDACInit()
{
    SIM_SCGC6 |= SIM_SCGC6_DAC0_MASK;
    DAC0_C0 |= DAC_C0_DACRFS_MASK;
    PORTE_PCR30 = PORT_PCR_MUX(0);
    DAC0_DAT0L = 0x00;
    DAC0_DAT0H |= 0x0;
    DAC0_DAT1L = 0xFF;
    DAC0_DAT1H |= 0xF;
    DAC0_C0 |= DAC_C0_DACEN_MASK;
}

void vfnDACSetValue(unsigned short wValue)
{
    DAC0_DAT0L = (unsigned char)(wValue & 0xFF);
    DAC0_DAT0H = (unsigned char)(wValue >> 8);
}

unsigned char bfnDACDriver(void)
{
    vfnDACSetValue(0xFF);
/*This is just a test; in my main, I'm just trying to see an output here.
But the main logic should be like the code below*/
    /*if(bflgSendingData){
        if(wSetPatternSize){
            vfnDACSetValue(wpSetPattern);
            wpSetPattern++;
            wSetPatternSize--;
        }
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
    */
}

unsigned char bfnDACSetPattern(unsigned short* wpPattern, unsigned short wPatternSize)
{
    if(0 == bflgSendingData){
        wpSetPattern = wpPattern;
        wSetPatternSize = wPatternSize;
        bflgSendingData = 1;
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

## UPDATE, forgot to include this file

Here is my DACDriver.h file

```
#ifndef __DACDRIVER_H_
#define __DACDRIVER_H_
#include "derivative.h"

void vfnDACInit(void);
unsigned char bfnDACDriver(void);
unsigned char bfnDACSetPattern(unsigned short* wpPattern, unsigned short wPatternSize);

#endif /* __DACDRIVER_H_ */
```

Here is my main.c file, which right now only has a little test so I can see some output

```
#include "DACDriver.h"
int main(void)
{
    unsigned char pattern[] = {
            0xFF, 0xEF, 0xDF, 0xCF, 0xBF, 0xAF, 
            0x9F, 0x8F, 0x7F, 0x6F, 0x5F, 0x4F, 0x3F, 0x2F, 0x1F, 
            0x0F, 0x0E, 0x0D, 0x0C, 0x0B, 0x0A, 
            0x09, 0x08, 0x07, 0x06, 0x05, 0x04, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00};
    vfnDACInit();
    for(;;) {
        bfnDACDriver();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to be the most autodidact possible, but I have run out of ideas...

My main questions are:
Do you see any error here? 
How do I make it work? 
Am I missing something?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: 1) Use `stdint.h` fixed bitwidth types for such tasks. The hardware registers should use them, too (otherwise this gives some impression on the quality of the provided headers/source code). 2) What was your question? 3) Use prototype declarators. `void vfnDACInit()` is not (you seem to mix then at will).

Comment: What does "no output" mean? I see that `bfnDACDriver()` called from `main()` outputs `0xFF`, ignoring the values in `unsigned char pattern[]` defined in `main()`.

Comment: Oh, and don't put function or object definitions in headers - except for Inline` functions.

Comment: What happens when you replace `0xFF` with `0x00`? Do you still get "no output"?

Comment: @Olaf 
1) I am trying not to use libraries, but thank you.
2) How do I make it to work? Do you see any errors? Sorry, I didn't see I did not put any actual question
3) My prototype declaration is inside my DACDriver.h file, which I didn't include.

Comment: `stdint.h` is not a library, but a header which is provided by all standard compliant C compilers. And you really should use these types, because they are exactly meant for this, while the basic types are not guaranted to provide a specific number of bits or a specific encoding for signed values either. Regarding the subject: as @WeatherVane already stated, you don't provide enough information. SO is not a remote debugging forum, but a Q&A site. It is not even clear if your problem is software or hardware based.

Comment: "Here is my header file ..." says different. Edit your question. Still, you do not use correct prototype declarators. Also enable all compiler warnings, at least `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion` (gcc, use the corresponding for your compiler).

Comment: @Olaf sorry, I am trying to reach experts in C so someone who knows more than me can tell what I am doing wrong, I am not asking anyone to debug for me. And I am doing my best in explaining myself. Thanks for all the replies.

Comment: @Porras: Well, you might not want to, but you actually do. So, last time: please provide the information required to help you. Use a debugger, read [ask], take the [tour]. Unteil then: good luck.

Comment: @WeatherVane I changed the value from 0xFF to 0x00 and still got no voltage rise in oscilloscope graph, thanks for replying

Comment: this line: `vfnDACSetValue(0xFF);` is only setting a single value, not a series of values.   I'm not familiar with the indicated platform,  however, on every system I have worked on 1) the DAC had to be enabled 2) each conversion has to be initiated, usually be writing a specific register in the DAC peripheral.  3) must not start another conversion until the prior conversion completes,  usually be checking some 'busy' bit in a status register of the DAC peripheral.  Could you clarify where/how these operations are being performed.

Comment: You do notice that the table: `pattern[]` is never being used.

Comment: Thanks @user3629249, I was not using my pattern but was expecting any rise in the oscilloscope's voltage instead with my 0xFF. My "state machine" is implemented in my DACDriver.c file

Answer (score 1):

So my real problem was not seeing that my oscilloscope didn't have the right voltage/time resolution hence the "null" output so to speak. My driver is fine. Thank you very much to everyone answering and taking an interest in my problem.